# GCC issue with template

Tags: c++, gcc, garbage-collection, compilation

I want to use the below garbage collector, but when I would compile I get a lot of error with GCC but not with VSC++, i.e this.

`list<GCInfo<T> >::iterator p;` ---> Expected ';' after expression

And here is the library.

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/A-Simple-Garbage-Collector-for-C-plus-plus/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `T` is a template parameter, you need a `typename`:

```
typename list<GCInfo<T> >::iterator p;
^^^^^^^^
```

For more about when and why `typename` is required, see the Stack Overflow C++ FAQ ["Where and why do I have to put `template` and `typename` on dependent names?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)